# Scroll to Top in ReactJs Component

Tags: reactjs

I have many search filters and a pagination component. I want to scroll to the top when the user clicks on the pagination component but not on the search filters components. Right now, even when the user clicks the search components, the page jumps to the top. How to prevent page scroll to the top when it is not pagination clicks? I am using a class component.

```
...
 constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.myRef = React.createRef()  
    }
 scrollToMyRef = () => window.scrollTo(0, this.myRef.current.offsetTop)   
  render() {
        return <div>
        <div id="search"><Search1 .../><Search2 .../></div>
        <div ref={this.myRef}><Pagination /></div> 
     </div>
    }
```

Comment: where and when do you call `scrollToMyRef`?

Comment: I don't need to call scrollToMyRef and it will scroll to top when clicking on Pagination component.

Comment: You must to attach the `scrollToMyRef` method on a `onClick` event from the `Pagination` component. Otherwise it will never trigger the desired scroll effect.